# Deterministic Simple Subset of English

Tags: technical

Is there a very restricted subset of English language that is more or less deterministic, captures most of the thoughts that can be expressed by humans and thus solves most of the communication issues we face in our day to day life?

We have so many words in english that each one has its own interpretation (In the sense of strength of emotion that a word describes). While expressing emotions are an essential part of a language, is there a very minimal subset that I can use to convey my ideas in the most simple manner and be confident that there is no way a certain statement can be misunderstood?

Comment: https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/science-in-ten-hundred-words-the-up-goer-five-challenge/

Comment: If people disagree about the existence of a concept then it does not matter how that concept is expressed, there will always be disagreement. The major disagreements on the international stage at this very moment are not about language or expression, they are about fundamental disagreement of concept.

Comment: "Thing Explainer" by Randall Monroe might show you a little of what this is like in practice. It’s scientific ideas (ISS, microwave oven) written using diagrams and the most common 1000 English words. I find it a little cryptic at times.

Comment: Broadly no, there isn’t. If there was, how would having many words with their interpretation be relevant?

There is no way any statement in English - nor so far as I know in any other language - could be guaranteed not to be misunderstood.

If you think emotions could be relevant, please explain how.

If you want a minimal subset to speak in the most simple manner, despite some risk of being misunderstood, consider the Swadesh sets, which exist for all major languages.

Ask your search engine of choice about “Swadesh (chosen tongue)”